# Display Included object fields in the datagrid - entity framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm using entity framewrok 4.3 in order to display tables from the database in a WPF DataGrid control.

I'm using generic  in order to represent EntityObject.
Some ObjectEntities hold related object and I want to display also the related objects properties.

This code I'm using returns QueryObject
context.CreateObjectSet().Include("RelatedObjectTable")

This code display only the type of the related object.
In the xaml, I'm using the DataGrid property AutoGenerateColumns ="True" and I want to keep this way.

How can I display the related object properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application.
It is a project that give a nice wizard to build a web project which reflect the 
database.

Answer (score 0):

AutoGenerateColumns will generate all the columns from your QueryObject. You can add additional columns from the related table this way:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RelatedProperty1" Binding="{Binding Path=RelatedObjectTable.Property1}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I wanted to create a dynamic build of the Grid... so I don't know how can I add related instances...

Comment: I would say Path=RelatedEntity.Property instead of RelatedObjectTable